# How to add a List to a List

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, multidimensional-array

I have an animalList that consist of type of animal, every animal has a visit list, where information is added for every time it has a visit for treatment.
Somehow I can not figure out how to a add the visit list to the animal list animalList.Add(listHealth) ????? Not working

```
List <Animal> animalList = new List <Animal>{typeOfAnimal = "Cat"};
DetailsOfAnimal da;

public class Animal
{
   public string typeOfAnimal;
   List <HealthList> listHealth = new List <HealthList>
}

public class HealthList
{
  public Date visit {get;set;}
  public string symptoms  {get;set;}
 }

.......
if new animal 
animalList = new List <Animal>;
// Add details to animal
da = new HealthList{visit = "2005-03-05", symptoms = "bad stomach"}
  List <HealthList> listHealth = new List <HealthList>
listHealth .Add(da);

animalList.Add(listHealth)   ???? Not working how to do that
```

Comment: Which `Animal` exactly do you want to add the `listHealth` to?

Comment: `listHealth.Add(new Animal() {typeOfAnimal="Cat", listHealth =da  });`

Comment: As far as I can see, `animalList` can contain `Animal` items only, and `HealthList` is not an `Animal` that's why you can add such items (via `AddRange`) into the list directty.

Comment: Btw. the name `HealthList` is a bit misleading. It's not describing a list. It's describing an item *in* a list. `Health` might also be misleading or at least be too undescriptive. Maybe `Visit` or `Treatment` would be better names for it. As for code style, I'd usually expect public members of classes to be upper case camel case (`TypeOfAnimal` instead of `typeOfAnimal`); but maybe your inhouse guidlines demand something different.

Comment: Why are `typeOfAnimal` and `listHealth` fields on `Animal`? They should be properties (with getter/setter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    private static List<Animal> animalList = new List<Animal>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal animal = new Animal() { TypeOfAnimal = "Dog" };
        // created a new animal

        animal.HealthList.Add(new Health() 
                              { 
                                  Visit = new DateTime(2014, 03, 05),
                                  Symptoms = "Herby is permanantly scratching his nose" 
                              });
        // added a new instance of Health to its HealthList
        // if you allready have a List<Health> the you can call
        // animal.HealthList.AddRange(theList); 
        // works as well with any other IEnumerable<Health>
        animalList.Add(animal);
    }
}

public class Animal
{
    private List<Health> healthList = new List<Health>(); 
    // the default accessmodifier for a classmember is private
    // you can write it too so you better understand what's going on

    public string TypeOfAnimal { get; set; }

    public List<Health> HealthList { get { return healthList; } }
    // add a readonly property for the list so you can access it from outside the class
}

public class Health 
// change this name for "HealthList" is missleading you
// because it would imply that it is a collection
{
    public DateTime Visit { get; set; }
    public string Symptoms { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You might want to change the type of "TypeOfAnimal" to an enum containing all animal types

Comment: (irony) a closed list of animals is the best thing, so when someone decides to do a health check on his pterodactyl and he discovers he can't, he will have to pay you to modify your program :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
animal.typeOfAnimal = "Cat";

da = new HealthList{visit = "2005-03-05", symptoms = "bad stomach"}
animal.listHealth.Add(da); // animal already has a non-null List<HealthList>

animalList.Add(animal);
```

You are reversing the order of the operations... It's better to first create the `Animal` (that already include a `listHealth`), and then populate the `listHealth`. You can `animalList.Add` at the end or immediately after the `new Animal()`. No difference.

And this is wrong:

```
List<Animal> animalList = new List <Animal>{typeOfAnimal = "Cat"};
```

It should be

```
List<Animal> animalList = new List<Animal>();
```

or

```
List<Animal> animalList = new List<Animal> { new Animal { typeOfAnimal = "Cat" } };
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add one list to another :

```
    list1.AddRange(list2);
```

Also see : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You cannot add lists of a different type to another.

In your case the animalList is of Generic Type Animal, and you are trying to add an entire List to it.

Comment: `HealthList` is not a subtype of `Animal`.